# this constructor takes no arguments: python

Tags: python, class

```
import random
import sys
import os

class Animal :
    __name=""
    __height=0
    __weight=0
    __sound=0

def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound):
    self.__name=name
    self.__height=height
    self.__weight=weight
    self.__sound=sound

def set_name(self,name):
    self.__name =name
def get_name(self):
    return self.__name
def set_height(self,height):
    self.__height =height
def get_height(self):
    return str(self.__height)
def set_weight(self,weight):
    self.__weight =weight
def get_weight(self):
    return str(self.__weight)
def set_sound(self,sound):
    self.__sound =sound
def get_sound(self):
    return self.__sound
def get_type(self):
    print("Animal")
def toString(self):
    return"{} is {} cm tall and {} kilograms and say{}".format(self.__name, self.__height,self.__weight,self.__sound)
cat = Animal('ruby',33,10,'meow')
print(cat.toString())
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 37, in <module>
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments
```

Comment: Is the indentation like that in your source file? If you don't indent the functions you're just creating global functions, and *not* class functions.

Comment: @MikeMüller Please don't edit indentation of Python files in cases like this. There's decent change your edit may obscure the source of the problem. Only fix the indentation is you're completely sure this isn't the problem.

Comment: @rakesh: always put spaces before and after `=` on variable assignments, not when passing parameters. This follows a standard called PEP8

Comment: Most of those functions are unnecessary anyway. Getter and setter functions aren't typically used for simple attribute access.

Answer (score 1):

class methods should be indented to be within the class

```
import random
import sys
import os

class Animal :
    __name=""
    __height=0
    __weight=0
    __sound=0

    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound):
        self.__name=name
        self.__height=height
        self.__weight=weight
        self.__sound=sound

    def set_name(self,name):
        self.__name =name
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name
    def set_height(self,height):
        self.__height =height
    def get_height(self):
        return str(self.__height)
    def set_weight(self,weight):
        self.__weight =weight
    def get_weight(self):
        return str(self.__weight)
    def set_sound(self,sound):
        self.__sound =sound
    def get_sound(self):
        return self.__sound
    def get_type(self):
        print("Animal")
    def toString(self):
        return"{} is {} cm tall and {} kilograms and say{}".format(self.__name, self.__height,self.__weight,self.__sound)
cat = Animal('ruby',33,10,'meow')
print(cat.toString())
```

This results in

`ruby is 33 cm tall and 10 kilograms and saymeow`

Answer (score 0):

classes have to be defined in one block. Also getters and setters are disadvised. The class-attributes should be deleted, because they are set as instance attributes.

```
class Animal:
    type = "Animal"

    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound):
        self.name = name
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
        self.sound = sound

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0.name} is {0.height} cm tall and {0.weight} kilograms and say {0.sound}".format(self)

    cat = Animal('ruby',33,10,'meow')
    print(cat)
```